# Squid Proxy and AD auth generating errors on Squid startup

Tags: linux, active-directory, squid, centos6, ntlm

I need some advice with an error i am getting when trying to start Squid which has integrated NTLM / AD auth setup.

heres the back story:

I've followed [this guide](http://janaps.wordpress.com/2010/05/30/squid-single-sign-on-with-active-directory/) word for word on the setup, installation and config of the server. So far everything has gone smoothly and i feel like i'm minutes away from getting this system running.

I am able to-do

```
Wbinfo -a administrator
kinit Administrator
klist
```

each command gives a confirmation that it ran successfully and worked as expected.

The Linux box has successfully joined my domain and i can do AD lookup's on users and groups.

however when i attempt to startup the squid service i get the following from the CLI.

```
[root@squid ~]# service squid start
Starting squid: .                                          [  OK  ]
```

But then get connection errors from my browser saying the proxy refused the connection, further investigation inside the /var/log/squid/cache.log for squid shows the following error.

```
2013/07/31 09:57:30| StatefulHandleRead: no callback data registered
2013/07/31 09:57:30| helperHandleRead: unexpected read from basicauthenticator #2, 28 bytes 'NT_STATUS_OK: Success (0x0)
'
2013/07/31 09:57:30| helperHandleRead: unexpected read from basicauthenticator #3, 28 bytes 'NT_STATUS_OK: Success (0x0)
'
2013/07/31 09:57:30| helperHandleRead: unexpected read from basicauthenticator #4, 28 bytes 'NT_STATUS_OK: Success (0x0)
'
2013/07/31 09:57:30| helperHandleRead: unexpected read from basicauthenticator #5, 28 bytes 'NT_STATUS_OK: Success (0x0)
'
2013/07/31 09:57:30| WARNING: ntlmauthenticator #3 (FD 13) exited
2013/07/31 09:57:30| WARNING: ntlmauthenticator #1 (FD 9) exited
2013/07/31 09:57:30| WARNING: ntlmauthenticator #2 (FD 11) exited
2013/07/31 09:57:30| Too few ntlmauthenticator processes are running
2013/07/31 09:57:30| storeDirWriteCleanLogs: Starting...
2013/07/31 09:57:30|   Finished.  Wrote 0 entries.
2013/07/31 09:57:30|   Took 0.00 seconds (  0.00 entries/sec).
FATAL: The ntlmauthenticator helpers are crashing too rapidly, need help!

Squid Cache (Version 3.1.10): Terminated abnormally.
CPU Usage: 0.143 seconds = 0.038 user + 0.105 sys
Maximum Resident Size: 35040 KB
Page faults with physical i/o: 0
Memory usage for squid via mallinfo():
        total space in arena:    2788 KB
        Ordinary blocks:         2757 KB     13 blks
        Small blocks:               0 KB      0 blks
        Holding blocks:          1012 KB      4 blks
        Free Small blocks:          0 KB
        Free Ordinary blocks:      30 KB
        Total in use:            3769 KB 135%
        Total free:                30 KB 1%
```

Here is a capture of the squid config file.

```
auth_param ntlm program /usr/bin/ntlm_auth -–helper-protocol=squid-2.5-ntlm --username=admin --password=password
auth_param ntlm children 10 
auth_param basic program /usr/bin/ntlm_auth -–helper-protocol=squid-2.5-basic --username=admin --password=password
auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm Domain Proxy Server
auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours
auth_param basic casesensitive off
authenticate_cache_garbage_interval 10 seconds
##
# Credentials past their TTL are removed from memory
authenticate_ttl 0 seconds
```

Comment: rpm -q squid; cat /etc/*-release

Comment: p.s. this isn't complete SSO configuration, with SSO, "auth_param negotiate" part is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you specifying the `--username` and `--password` arguments to `ntlm_auth`? Those arguments aren't necessary and are likely causing the`ntlm_auth` processes to terminate (which is, likely, the root cause of your failure).

Comment: The reason i was specifying them was down to a walkthrough i found about configuring NTLM_Auth that showed the username & password option, not having prior experience i had to make the guess that these were needed.